# Ajax beforesend, succes, complete, loading icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento-1.9

So this is my "addtocart" function.

```
$(document).on("addtocart", function(e, object) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $object = $(object);
  var target = $(object).attr("action");
  var quantity = $(object).find(".qty").val();
  var productID = $(object).data("productid");
  $.ajax({
    url: target,
    data: {
      qty: quantity
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      if ($object.find(".loading").length < 1) {
        $object.append('<div class="loading"><span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></span></div>');
      } else {
        $("#item_" + productID).removeClass("added");
      }
      $("#item_" + productID).addClass("adding");
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.r === "success") {
        var blocks = data.update_blocks;
        $.each(blocks, function(key, item) {
          var block = blocks[key];
          $(block.key).html(block.value.trim());
        });
        $("#jm-mycart").trigger("show");
        $("#item_" + productID).removeClass("adding").addClass("added");
        if ($("#item_" + productID + " td:first-child").find(".added").length < 1) $("#item_" + productID + " td:first-child").append('<div class="added"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></div>');
      } else {
        alert("Noget gik galt");
      }
    },
    complete: function() {
      $object.find(".loading").remove();
    }
  });
  return false;
})
```

My problem is that whenever I add an item for the first time, the loading appears. But after that no. 2 odd things about this.

First, it works just fine on product pages, it is only on category pages this happens.

Second, When I don't try to remove the loading on completion, it works fine on category pages, but of course, gets stuck on product pages.

I really can't seem to work my way out of this. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it is a css conflict and you need to use a more unique className? Hard to help without a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: omg:) It looks like u were right... Ty. Solved my problem.